# Laravel The page has expired due to inactivity error for get request from outside of site

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I implemented simple payment method to connect to bank and get result and check payment status with `/product/payment/checkTransaction` url, i dont have any problem to connect to bank, but after click on cancel i want to check payment transaction with `/product/payment/checkTransaction` url but i get error:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity.
Please refresh and try again.
```

my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web'], function () {
    $this->post('/product/payment', 'Dashboard\PaymentController@payment');
    $this->post('/product/payment/checkTransaction', 'Dashboard\PaymentController@checkTransaction');
});
```

Payment class:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $api_key = "XXXX";

    public function payment()
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'product_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        //connect to bank

    }

    public function checkTransaction()
    {
        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

BTW i added `/product/payment/checkTransaction` url to class:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        '/dashboard/administrator/attachImage',
        '/product/payment/checkTransaction'
    ];
}
```

how can i resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

this message happens in laravel versions >=5.5, and it happens when laravel can not correctly find the route.

you say that you click on the cancel button, so I'm guessing you use GET method. change Route::post to Route::get and see if it works.